# Up the hill with 3 legs and back down with 4

Tags: riddle

Though I'm not alive, I had 4 legs when I was born.
I lost a leg when I got too stressed and worn.
I go up the hill with just 3 legs, and come down the hill with 4.
If my owner doesn't lose some weight, I'll be going up the hill some more!

Comment: https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080326000535AA6M06I

Comment: @JayeshJain that link's "best answer" (by Pepper Shaker) is in the right direction. my question has a different answer though.

Comment: As demonstrated by that link though, there's many "acceptable" answers, thus this question will probably get closed as too broad... Can you add some more meat to it, to help restrict the possibly correct solutions? Otherwise, we're just playing "Guess what RedCaio is thinking"...

Comment: @Alconja I edited the question. how's that?

Comment: @RedCaio - Significantly better. Still possibly multiple answers, but superficially at least, it looks enough to avoid the "too broad" label. Welcome to Puzzling.SE. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe

> A chair.

Though I'm not alive, I had 4 legs when I was born.

> 4 legs and not alive. Sounds like a chair to me.

I lost a leg when I got too stressed and worn.

> Stressed and worn - a chair leg broke because of a large weight. (applying pressure causes stress and can wear down wood)

I go up the hill with just 3 legs, and come down the hill with 4.

> ? I suppose that someone who fixes chairs has his office at the top of a hill for some reason.

If my owner doesn't lose some weight, I'll be going up the hill some more!

> Well, if the owner is heavy, he's bound to break that chair leg again sooner or later.